# Find specific data-availability class

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following webpage source:

```
<li class="available" data-availability="homeDelivery">
    <i class="icon-tick"></i> FREE delivery 
</li>
```

I want to print "Free delivery" to the screen if data-availability == homeDelivery.

I tried with the below code but I get no match.

```
result = soup.find_all("option", {"data-availability": 'homeDelivery'})
print(result)
```

ANy ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for `<li>` tag not `option`.

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<li class="available" data-availability="homeDelivery">
    <i class="icon-tick"></i> FREE delivery 
</li>"""

result = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all("li", {"data-availability": 'homeDelivery'})
print([i.getText(strip=True) for i in result])
```

Output:

```
['FREE delivery']
```